# Server 2012 Email alert if there is a power outage

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I have a old Windows 2012 Server with AD installed in it. How can I configure Email Alert on it if the server goes down due to a Power outage? I don't have UPS installed for the server as well.
Is there any way or a PowerShell script we can have to trigger this as I know in windows 2012 email alerts are deprecated.

Comment: ..But.. if the server shuts down because of a power outage, it won't be able to mail would it??

Comment: @Theo Thank you for the message , i need to get an email when the event triggered  after the server boots.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server create a scheduled task that executes on boot. This task can send an email after every server restart.

The Windows Event log will contain events with ID 6008 (which means "The previous system shutdown at time on date was unexpected") - ie power-cut or other unplanned shutdown. You might also be interested in event id 1074 which is "System has been shutdown by a process/user" ie a normal reboot/shutdown. You can retrieve events from the event log with Powershell using `Get-EventLog`

---

Edit:

You should be able to use `Send-MailMessage` to send email from powershell 3 on server 2012 - *but* you will need an SMTP server that will accept unencrypted traffic (which is a separate problem).

Server 2012 is old and approaching end of support, but its already in extended support - this means no new features are getting added. This includes adding support for new cryptographic standards so your options for SMTP are going to be limited.

As this is your DC i assume you have other more modern servers available? It might be easier to use one of them to monitor your DC and send the message? Another option would be to setup an SMTP relay on another internal server that forwards the unencrypted messages from your dc and encrypts them - not ideal but good enough as a temporary hack.

Comment: Hi MisterSmith, Thank you for the message, this server is windows 2012 so email alerts are depreciated is there any alternative?

Comment: Hi MisterSmith,  can you help me on how to configure email -alert from another server to monitor the 2012 Server?

Comment: I cant give you a full solution - it will depend a lot on your setup/knowledge. My advice is to break the problem into parts and tackle them separately. On a modern domain joined server does `Send-MailMessage` work? Depending on your domain/email setup this should probably work for internal email (if not you need SMTP credentials to send email and maybe firewall changes). Research powershell remoting - used from your modern server you can connect to the DC and check its uptime with command `Get-CimInstance`, then based on that, send an email from the modern server.